# Postgres update column value to time.Now()

Tags: postgresql

I need to update column `paid_at` to `time.Now()` on table `orders` when column `status` is updated to `paid` is it possible to create a trigger on postgres? they are all in a same table `orders`

Comment: "is it possible to create a trigger" -- Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to create a trigger on postgres

Yes, that's possible.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) you need a trigger *function* first:

```
create function update_paid_at()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.paid_at := now();
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpglsql;
```

Then you need a [trigger definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

```
create trigger update_orders_trigger
   before update on orders
   for each row
   when (new.status = 'paid' and new.status <> old.status)
   execute procedure update_paid_at();
```

The trigger only fires if the status is *changed* to `'paid'` and then sets the value of `paid_at` column.